# magento system.xml <backend_model> validate two parameter using same method

Tags: magento-1.9

I have two system config fields like password and password confirm field.i need to validate both are same.
for this in my `system.xml` file i added `<backend_model>` note to both fields

```
 <backend_model>myextension/test</backend_model>
```

in my model folder i created `Test.php` class as below

```
class Mycomany_Myextension_Model_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{


public function _afterSave()
    {
        $licence = $this->getValue(); //get the value from our config
        print_r($licence);
        die();

        return parent::_afterSave();
    }



}
```

**EDIT**

My system config values

```
<input id="filemaker_general_fburl" name="groups[general][fields][fburl][value]" value="test" class=" input-text" type="text">


<input id="filemaker_general_fbheight" name="groups[general][fields][fbheight][value]" value="123" class=" input-text" type="text">
```

but it only return one value instead of two.i don't know what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$licence = $this->getValue();` return only current field value

Try following way to pick other value

```
$anotherValue = $this->getData('groups/[name_of_group]/fields/[name_of_field]/value');
```

example: echo $anotherValue = $this->getData('groups/general/fields/fbwidth/value');

Comment: it 's returning blank page <input id="filemaker_general_fbwidth" name="groups[general][fields][fbwidth][value]" value="abc" class=" input-text" type="text"> this is inspected code echo $anotherValue = $this->getData('groups/[general]/fields/[fbwidth]/value');

Comment: check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   $storeId = 2; // ID of the store you want to fetch the value of
   or
   $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();// Gets the current store's id

 echo $configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('groups/general/fields/fbwidth/value', $storeId);
```

Comment: Please explain what your code is doing and how it is solving the OP's problem. "Code only" answers can be unclear to future readers that run into similar problems.

Comment: I have two system configuration fields.I need to validate bath fileds are same or not.but $licence = $this->getValue();  is give only one fields.i need to get both fields after save it

Comment: updated ans pls check now